# The certificate of repo.myql.com is not trusted

Tags: mysql, debian

I am trying to install MySQL 5.7 on Debian Stretch by following this tutorial:

https://dbahire.com/how-to-install-mysql-server-on-debian-stretch/

As you know Debian Stretch comes with MariaDB instead of MySQL that's why I am doing it. Anyway I am facing issue at following step:

`wget -O /tmp/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql https://repo.mysql.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql`

The error I am getting is:

`The certificate of repo.myql.com is not trusted`

One option is to use `wget --no-check-certificate` but this is not good practice.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I fix this issue?

There really isn't anything you can do except perhaps notify the site owner as the certificate is outside your control.

FWIW you command works fine for me now on F27 and Qualys SSL Checker says it's OK too.